# Creating a css selector to locate multiple ids in a single-shot

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, css-selectors, lxml

I've defined css selectors within the script to get ***the text within `span` elements*** and I'm getting them accordingly. However, the way I tried is definitely messy. I just seperated different css selectors using comma to let the script understand I'm after this or that.

If I opt for xpath I could have used `'div//span[.="Featured" or .="Sponsored"]'` but in case of css selector I could not find anything similar to serve the same purpose. I know using `'span:contains("Featured"),span:contains("Sponsored")'` I can get the text but there is the comma in between as usual.

***What is the ideal way to locate the elements (within different ids) using css selectors except for comma?***

My try so far with:

```
from lxml.html import fromstring

html = """
<div class="rest-list-information">
    <a class="restaurant-header" href="/madison-wi/restaurants/pizza-hut">
        Pizza Hut
    </a>
    <div id="featured other-dynamic-ids">
        <span>Sponsored</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="rest-list-information">
    <a class="restaurant-header" href="/madison-wi/restaurants/salads-up">
        Salads UP
    </a>
    <div id="other-dynamic-ids border">
        <span>Featured</span>
    </div>
</div>
"""

root = fromstring(html)
for item in root.cssselect("[id~='featured'] span,[id~='border'] span"):
    print(item.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
.rest-list-information div span
```

But I think it's a bad idea to consider the comma messy. You won't find many stylesheets that don't have commas.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to get all 'span' text from the HTML then the following should suffice:

```
root_spans = root.xpath('//span')

for i, root_spans in enumerate(root_spans):
    span_text = root_spans.xpath('.//text()')[0]
    print(span_text)
```